# Increase in SSD performance?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a 120GB Samsung 840 EVO and I'd heard they had an issue with decreasing performance. So I re-ran CrystalDiskMark on the drive and compared it to the numbers I ran when I originally purchased the drive 2.5 years ago. It looks as though the numbers have gone up.

Am I misreading the test results, is it a driver update, or a windows 10 thing?

```
First Test
         Sequential Read :   430.509 MB/s
        Sequential Write :   104.847 MB/s
       Random Read 512KB :   422.222 MB/s
      Random Write 512KB :   139.009 MB/s
  Random Read 4KB (QD=1) :    22.247 MB/s [  5431.4 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KB (QD=1) :    41.116 MB/s [ 10038.2 IOPS]
 Random Read 4KB (QD=32) :   206.679 MB/s [ 50458.8 IOPS]
Random Write 4KB (QD=32) :    80.859 MB/s [ 19741.1 IOPS]
Test : 1000 MB [C: 20.3% (22.7/111.8 GB)] (x5)
Date : 2013/11/30 15:24:24
OS : Windows 8.1  [6.3 Build 9600] (x64)

Second Test
   Sequential Read (Q= 32,T= 1) :   549.563 MB/s
  Sequential Write (Q= 32,T= 1) :   416.801 MB/s
  Random Read 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :   362.435 MB/s [ 88485.1 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :   282.439 MB/s [ 68954.8 IOPS]
         Sequential Read (T= 1) :   498.462 MB/s
        Sequential Write (T= 1) :   417.939 MB/s
   Random Read 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :    38.788 MB/s [  9469.7 IOPS]
  Random Write 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :   125.768 MB/s [ 30705.1 IOPS]

Test : 1024 MiB [C: 67.5% (75.2/111.3 GiB)] (x5)  [Interval=5 sec]
Date : 2016/04/25 23:32:04
OS : Windows 10 Professional N [10.0 Build 10586] (x64)
```

Comment: use the latest firmware + perf restore tool: http://www.thessdreview.com/daily-news/latest-buzz/samsung-840evo-performance-degradation-follow-up-latest-firmware-update-and-magician-4-6-software-now-available/

Comment: The performance difference is so large in the 4KB tests that the only conclusion is that there was something wrong in the test you did years ago, maybe a bad SATA driver that got updated

Comment: It is impossible to determine why this performance increase has happened. There currently is insufficient data to be able to give an objective answer. This makes this question Offtopic for SuperUser because it becomes opinion based.

Comment: Without you using the exact same version of CrystalDiskMark all benchmarks comparisons should be considered suspect. We've no idea what performance features were unsupported between the two versions you used.